# Why AM I getting 30 VAC @ 52 A?

Tags: transformer, amperage

Why am I getting 30 VAC @ 52 A?

I have three identical transformers with a secondary, 20/10 VAC (8.8/17.6 A). I connected them is series to get 30 VAC across a heating band with a very low resistance (0.5 ohms). Power is applied to reach a set temperature and keep it for 1 - 3 s in series of short pulses to seal a plastic bag. In theory three transformers @ 10 VAC connected in series will measure 17.6 A across, but instead I'm getting 52.8 A (3 × 17.6 = 52.8). How is that possible?

Comment: 20V*7A and 10V*14A are both 140W. *3 = 420W whether series or parallel. So you certainly aren't getting 52A at 30V from the three transformers described.

Comment: You don’t measure current by connecting the ammeter across the transformer output like you would to measure voltage. If you did it this way you’d be measuring the short circuit current which can be way in excess of the rated current. This is not recommended. See sphero’s response.

Comment: I connected the trans to a heating element with a very low resistance, so I do not have short circuit, that is for sure, but I'm getting 52A instead of 17.6A. The trans are connected in series, but reacting as if they where in parallel adding the current. The power is been applied for 2-3 secs in short pulses to keep the set point. It is a bag sealing process. Thanks Kartman

Comment: 1. What is the measured output voltage of the transformers with load disconnected and when load is connected? 2. How are you measuring 52 A? Put all the information into your question.

Answer (score 6):

The *rated* output current will be 30VAC at 14A (or 60 VAC at 7A).

If  you short out the 30VAC you may well get something like 52A, however the voltage will be zero and the transformers will burn out in rather short order.

Answer (score 1):

The load resistance of 0.5 \$\Omega\$ is too small for the transformers you are using.

Theoretically, if the transformers, wired in series give you 30 V output, and this 30  volts is applied across a 0.5 \$\Omega\$ load, there will be 60 amps current. (\$I = \frac{V}{R}\$) You would probably get less due to voltage sag. However, 60 amps current is beyond the rating of your transformers (which is 14 A). You are likely to burn out your transformers quite quickly with such a load.

Answer (score 1):

30V and a 0.5 ohm resistor would theoretically give you 60A.

Transformers have no overload protection.  If you attempt to draw a current in excess of what they are rated for, then you will get a large current.  The voltage may drop, though.  That may be why you're only getting 52A.

Note that if you put transformers in series, then the voltages add.  But not the current rating.

If you keep drawing that current for a long period, then they will overheat and burn out.  If it's only 1-3 seconds, then they probably won't.  But it's not a good thing to do, and they may fail early if misused like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect as follows:

- **Series**: will add the voltages but keep the current the same.
- **Parallel**: will add the currents but keep the voltage the same.

---

- Series gives you 3 × 10 V @ 14 A = 30 V @ 14 A.
- Parallel gives you 3 × 14 A @ 10 V = 10 V @ 42 A.